# How to prove "Unit digit of a square number"?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

> How can I prove that the unit digit of a perfect square is always $0,1,4,9,5,6$ and never $2,3,7,8$?

It's pretty intuitive but I am having difficulties  proving this statement. 
 I had used trial and error to get to that statement.

**Note**(The original problem was: If the length and width of a rectangle are consecutive positive integers and the area has $6$ in its unit digit.Is it possible to say that one of the length or width is a perfect square number ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any integer can be written as $10n+r$ where $n,r$ are integers with $0\leq r<10$. Then the unit digit of the square 
$$(10n+r)^2=100n+20rn+r^2=10(\underbrace{10n+2rn}_{\text{integer}})+r^2$$
is equal to the unit digit of $r^2$. So it suffices to  consider the unit digit of $r^2$ when $r\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Thus we may conclude that the unit digit of any perfect square belongs to the set 
$$\{\text{unit digit of $r^2$}: r\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\}=\{0,1,4,9,6,5\}.$$

P.S. As regards the original question, a product of two consecutive integers has a unit digit $6$ iff we multiply factors with unit digits $2$ and $3$, or $7$ and $8$. It follows that none of these factors can be a perfect square.

Comment: Is that the formal proof ?

Comment: My hint is the proof that the unit digit of a perfect square belongs to the set of unit digits of the squares $r^2$ with $r\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted my question. I know what you answered. When I said I got it from trial and error , my conclusion was same as yours. I really wanted a formal solution.

Comment: My answer IS a formal proof of what you asked, I guess...

Answer (score 4):

You can write your number in the form $$n=10k+r_i$$ with $$r_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$ and square it.

Comment: Do you mean $10k + r_i$?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean!

Answer (score 0):

Use the modular arithmetic:
$$\begin{align} n&\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow \\
n^2&\equiv 0^2,1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,5^2,6^2,7^2,8^2,9^2 \\
&\equiv 0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81 \\
&\equiv 0,1,4,9,6,5,6,9,4,1 \pmod{10}.\end{align}$$